# Getting an unwanted 1px extra height per DIV table element in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-tables

I have an issue with a table containing three cells in one row. Two of these (left and right) have fixed width/height and should display an image (or shrink to 0 when no image is present). The middle cell takes the remaining space withing the fixed total with of the table.

The problem: now I end up with 3px of extra space by which the 'image containers' seem to expand (below the cells). You can see it by inspecting the 'starredunread' element for example, it grows from 20px to 23px in height. And I have no idea what's happening as the margin / padding is already turned off by default and border:0 and border-collapse: collapse doesn't help.

Here's the CSS file:

```
/*------------------------------------------

Reset (from the Yahoo UI Library)

------------------------------------------*/



body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {margin:0;padding:0;}

table{border-collapse:collapse;}

fieldset,img{border:0;}

address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}

ol,ul{list-style:none;}

caption,th{text-align:left;}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}

q:before,q:after{content:'';}

abbr,acronym{border:0}

a{outline: none;} 



/*------------------------------------------

Interface

------------------------------------------*/

body {

top: 0px;

left: 0px;

width: 320px;

height: 480px;

background-color: #f00;

color: #000;

font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;

font-size: 12px;

}

.header {

display: table;

top: 0px;

left: 0px;

width: 320px;

height: 44px;

background-color: #738ba3;

color: #fff;

table-layout: fixed;

border: 0;

border-spacing: 0;

}

.headerrow {

display: table-row;

}


.text {

display: table-cell;

overflow: hidden;

text-overflow: ellipsis;

white-space: nowrap;

padding-left: 2px;

vertical-align: middle;

}

.text b {

font-weight: 700;

font-size: 11pt;

}

.date {

display: table-cell;

width: 50px;

vertical-align: middle;

text-align: right;

font-size: 8pt;

padding-top: 3px;

padding-right: 5px;

}

.date b {

font-weight: 700;

line-height: 11pt;

}


.starredunread {

display: table-cell;

top: 0px;

left: 0px;

width: 20px;

height: 44px;

vertical-align: middle;

}

.icon {

display: table-cell;

top: 0px;

right: 0px;

width: 44px;

height: 44px;

}


.content {

display: table;

width: 320px;

background-color: #fff;

color: #000;

font-size: 12pt;

text-align: left;

padding: 15px;

}

.sectionheader {

height: 20px;

}

.sectionheaderrow {

}

.sectionunread {

height: 20px;

}

.sectiontext {

font-weight: 700;

font-size: 9pt;

padding-top: 1px;

}

.smallicon {

width: 20px;

height: 20px;

}
```

And here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>testHTML</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="header">

    <div class="headerrow">

        <div class="starredunread">
            <img src="images/testimg_small.png">
        </div><!-- end starredunread -->

        <div class="text">
                <b>Testheader</b><br>
                Text for testing - this should overflow with an ellipsis if the text exceeds the size of the container...
        </div><!-- end text -->

        <div class="date">
                <b>11.11.09</b><br>
                18:54
        </div><!-- end date -->

        <div class="icon">
            <img src="images/testimg_44x44.png">
        </div><!-- end icon -->

    </div><!-- end headerrow -->

</div> <!-- end header -->

<div class="content">
    More text for testing purposes.<br><br>Not really relevant.<br><br> So don't waste your time reading this. :o)
</div><!-- end content -->

<div class="header sectionheader">

    <div class="headerrow sectionheaderrow">

        <div class="starredunread sectionunread">
            <img src="images/testheader.png">
        </div><!-- end sectionunread -->

        <div class="text sectiontext">
            Another Header
        </div><!-- end sectiontext" -->

        <div class="icon smallicon">
            <img src="images/testimg_20x20.png">
        </div><!-- end smallicon -->

    </div><!-- end sectionheaderrow -->

</div><!-- end sectionheader -->

</body> 

</html>
```

... doesn't look too nice without the images but it demonstrates my problem anyway.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your input! The code only needs to work in Safari / Webkit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In strict mode images are inline by default, since you're using strict you need to fix this manually by applying `display:block` to your images.

> "In the early days, experiments with strict mode invariably raised the
>   comment that images suddenly got an odd bottom margin that couldn’t be
>   removed. The cause was that in strict mode  is an inline
>   element, which means that some space should be reserved for possible
>   descender characters like g, j, or q. Of course an image doesn’t have
>   descender characters, so the space was never used, but it still had to
>   be reserved.
>
> The solution was to explicitly declare images block level elements:
>   img {display: block}."
>
> http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: wow - that was quick, simple and: effective! thanks a lot, fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. Generally, you have to inhibit margins and padding on ALL css elements with the following markup (preferably at the start of your style sheet):
* {
   margins: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

The leading '*' is important. This saves several hours of frustration.
Afterward, if you have a text cell it may seem as if there still is half an em of padding at the top, but that's because most text characters are shorter than an em.